# How to find the equivalence point on a graph of an acid-base titration curve?

Tags: ph, titration

Here is the data taken from the lab:
**Acid pH, Vol (cm3)**[
(9.67,  4cm3)
(9.08,  8cm3)
(8.70,  10cm3)
(8.06,  12cm3)
(7.93,  13cm3)
(4.76,  14cm3)
(2.45,  15cm3)
(2.23,  16cm3)
(2.10,  17cm3)
(2.01,  18cm3)
(1.94,  19cm3)
(1.88,  20cm3)]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer *per se*, however:

- If you were to titrate an acid in aqueous solution, why would be the pH value in the beginning superior to 7?  Because reading the data provided suggests you added the acid (to be characterized, so your question) instead.
- The data interval is too coarse, especially in the region "something is happening", at about 13 mL to 16 mL.   Repeat the experiment (with correct addition of the reagents), and while adding the base to the acid, keep a log running.  Like:
  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  \text{pH value}& \text{total added volume of base} & \Delta\ce{pH} &\Delta V & \frac{\Delta \text{pH}}{\Delta V}\\
  \hline
  \ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
  \ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
  \end{array}

Where $\Delta\ce{pH}$ is the change of the pH-value since the last addition of the reagent (conversely, $\Delta V$ the volume of reagent added since the last addition.

From the poor (because very little) data here, the plateau-like data provided by you (esp. pH 4.76) that is away from 7 might be indicative for a weak acid; like acetic acid, for example.  So read about [equivalence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_point) of weak acids (and bases), and how this differs from strong acids.  When you reach the equivalent point(s), small quantities of bases / acids added may yield a significant change in the pH value; a volumetric analysis reducing the volume of added reagent to 0.1 mL in this particular region is not uncommon.  And dervivate from the reading (the lower section of the reference provides some links).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the result in R

```
titration <- data.frame(Vol=c(4,8,10,12:20),
                        pH=c(9.67, 9.08, 8.70, 8.06, 7.93,4.76,2.45,2.23,2.10,2.01,1.94,1.88))

plot(titration$Vol,titration$pH, main="Acid Base Titration",
      xlab="Volume /ml", ylab="pH")
```

If you copy and paste the code into r-fiddle.org you'll get your graph and result.

Comment: I would have used matplotlib on a dataframe from a list of tuples in Python. Admittedly, the short in R notation for the volume range `12:20` is pretty neat!

Comment: I used R because the OP can simply post the code into the web page I gave and get the result.  No software downloads needed etc...

Comment: Good point! If I remember correctly, wakari.io requires (free) registration.

Comment: As to whether or not the OP does anything with the answer is a different matter.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but I found your answer useful and upvoted. More often than not, it is helpful to plot the data before one starst to fiddle around with them.

Comment: I don't find this answer helpful at all, therefore I downvoted. I don't even consider this a valid answer. To be fair, I don't find the question helpful at all, too, so I downvoted that also.